# Lenovo P51s ThinkPad laptop continuously cycles power on and off. Why is this happening and how can it be fixed?

Tags: laptop, power, lenovo-laptop, laptop-repair

This morning, when I tried to turn my Lenovo P51s ThinkPad laptop on (it was on my desk, untouched from where I'd left it last night), it started the process (keyboard lights up, fan turns on), then turned off after ~2s and repeated the process ad infinitum. Pressing the power button turned it off.

This happened even if I disconnected the power supply and (!) the battery. Looks like it has some sort of internal battery, in addition to the removable one, today I learned.

Activating the hard-reset button on the back with a pin also didn't fix the issue.

Has anyone encountered something like this before?

Comment: do you have anything plugged in to it (e.g. external mouse/monitor)? if so, remove it

Comment: have you tried reseating the RAM (if that is possible on the Lenovo P51s)?

Comment: 1. Can you enter BIOS? Press and hold F1 while powering on:https://pcsupport.lenovo.com/us/en/products/laptops-and-netbooks/thinkpad-p-series-laptops/thinkpad-p51-type-20hh-20hj/20hj/solutions/ht500222-recommended-ways-to-enter-bios-boot-menu-thinkpad-thinkcentre-thinkstation 2. If so, try to boot from USB, e.g., with Win PE (as in Hiren's Boot CD) or Linux (as from Ubuntu Live), and check the internal drive of the laptop. It could be dead.

Comment: If you can enter into the BIOS/UEFI, try to do a Reset.

Comment: Thanks for all the comments. F1 did not do anything, it turned off too soon. What helped was letting it drain completely after taking out the removable battery. It started up, BSODd after 1/2h, and now won't start. I'm guessing motherboard issue, but I'll see if it's possible to re-seat the RAM just in case.

Comment: This sort of issue is going to be exceptionally difficult to diagnose remotely, even by someone who has experience the precise set of symptoms previously, due to the nature of hardware issues. However, what is clear is that it is most likely to be a hardware issue, and the correct course for these is to make use of whatever warranty you have on the computer, if you have one, and if not, take the computer to a competent local pc hardware technician for diagnosis and service.